# How to pass additional arguments to npm task via Gradle command line?

Tags: node.js, gradle, npm, gradle-node-plugin

Assume in my package.json I have a task named "xxx".

Using npm itself, I can run it as follows: `npm run xxx`.

I also can run it with additional arguments in the following way: `npm run xxx -- more arguments for xxx`.

Using gradle-node-plugin, I can run it via Gradle using `./gradlew npm_run_xxx`.

But is there a way to pass those additional arguments to the npm task, like I've done above with npm right on the Gradle command line?

What I've tried, and it doesn't work: `./gradlew npm_run_xxx --args="more args"`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you add them into the Gradle script as defined here:
https://github.com/node-gradle/gradle-node-plugin/blob/master/docs/usage.md

Gradle (Groovy):

```
npm_update {
  args = ['--production', '--loglevel', 'warn']
}
```

Gradle (Kotlin):

```kotlin
tasks.named<NpmTask>("npm_update") {
  args.set(listOf("--production", "--loglevel", "warn"))
}
```